# MySQL REGEXP search multiple words

Tags: mysql, regex, select

The field `Products.Name` contains `PETISCO NESTLE PURINA DOG CHOW CARINHOS MIX DE FRUTAS`

I need search de word `DOG` and the word `NESTEL` (wrong word) but the first three letters are correct.
I don't know the order of the words.

I tried same thing like this `REGEXP '[^DOG][^NESTEL]{3}'` but doesn't work!

thanks

**Update 1:**

When the user types DOG and NESTEL I want my app to show all products that contain the words DOG and NESTLE, even part of the word is wrong!

**Update 2:**

```
where Products.Name REGEXP '[[:<:]]?=*NES.*[[:>:]]' and Products.Name REGEXP '[[:<:]]?=*DOG.*[[:>:]]'
```

This shows me the dog E NES but if the user types NESTEL and not NESTLE?

Comment: Can you please explain the issue? `[^DOG]` is a non `d`, `o`, or `g` character.

Comment: MySQL's `REGEXP` doesn't support lookaround assertions.

Comment: Start with word DOG and NES***

Comment: A word can't start with `DOG` and `NES` do you mean one or the other, or you want to find a `dog` and then a word that starts with `NES`?

Comment: What is wrong with the current expression you have? `but if the user types NESTEL and not NESTLE?` is not a complete statement.

Comment: I think this notation below can help me but I do not know how to use it.

{n} or {m,n} notation provides a more general way of writing regular expressions that match many occurrences of the previous atom (or “piece”) of the pattern. m and n are integers.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [levenshtein function](https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/levenshtein-and-levenshtein_ratio-functions-for-mysql/) for mysql. It goes through all the results evaluating them according to it's similarity to the searched word (i.e. NESTEL) and return them with that extra ratio field. Then you only have to select the one with a higher ratio, or a list with the ones more similar... etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE Name REGEXP '[[:<:]]dog[[:>:]]'
      AND Name REGEXP '[[:<:]]nes';
```

- You wanted "dog" to be a "word", hence the word boundary thingies.
- You wanted some "word" starting with "nes", hence the word-start thingie only.
- It does not check for 6 letters in "nes...", that would be

  ```
    AND Name REGEXP '[[:<:]]nes[a-z]{3}[[:>:]]';
  ```

There *may* be a collation issue; please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Mini-lesson:

- `[^DOG]` says "match 1 bytes, but not `D`, nor `O`, nor `G`.
- `[^NESTEL]{3}` says match exactly 3 bytes, but they cannot be any of those 6 letters.
- MySQL does not handle any of the operators _starting with `?`
- `NES.*[[:>:]]` matches `NES`, followed by the rest of the string -- This is because `*` is "greedy" and that `[[:>:]]` will match the end of string.
- LIKE '%dog%nes%' has no tests for word boundries.
- `nes***` as a regexp would say `ne` followed by any number of `s`, including zero.
- `nes...` would match `nes` plus 3 bytes of any kind.  So, all it says it that the `nes` must not be too near the end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE some_col LIKE '%dog%nes%' or some_col LIKE '%nes%dog%'
```

Comment: word dog AND nes***

Comment: Don't understand the down vote - my guess is as good as anyone's since he's not really clear on what he wants or what his data looks like. Geez.

Comment: Not my vote but answers shouldn't be guesses. Answers also should include an explanation.

Comment: Will find anything and not find words